# Code clarity for converting generic list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

This code should convert the list of listType2s (list) to a list of type1s. I feel the functionality is somewhat difficult to ascertain though.

I am looking to see alternative methods that are easier to read, yet concise, and brief.

```
        List<Type1> type1s = new List<Type1>();
        listType2s.ForEach(t => type1s.Add((new Type1(t))));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally agree with using LINQ for this sort of thing - but `List<T>` has had a `ConvertAll` method since .NET 2.0 which will actually be slightly more efficient (as it already knows the size):

```
List<Type1> type1s = listType2s.ConvertAll(t => new Type1(t));
```

I would *probably* use LINQ myself unless I had a particular reason not to, just because then it's consistent with the rest of the code which would probably be using LINQ too.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like:

```
var type1s = (from item in listType2s select new Type1(item)).ToList();
```

I should say, I *actually* prefer

```
var qry = from item in listType2s 
          select new Type1(item);
var type1s = qry.ToList();
```

But mostly because that lets me reuse `qry` for other nefarious purposes if I want to.

Comment: @Randiolpho I think this code shows the intent the clearest out of the linq methods but is not as clear as using the built-in method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
var type1s = listType2s.Select(o => new Type1(o)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the clearest way is the following

```
var type1s = listType2s.Select(x => new Type1(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are upcasting, this is a clear and concise idiom:

```
List<SubType> list1 = GetListSubType();
List<BaseType> list2 = list1.OfType<BaseType>().ToList();
```